# Meteor suddenly stopped working - Bus error 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, osx-mavericks

my Meteor Server suddenly stopped and my app wont restart again. I was just editing some SCSS files and all i get is

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
Bus error: 10he application
```

when i try to to run meteor.

I'm on OSX 10.9.5, nodejs and meteor are the newest versions

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, what you can try is deleting the Meteor build (`/.meteor/local` folder). It *sometimes* fixes stuff.

Comment: If the above doesn't help I would also try a fresh meteor install.

Comment: I had a Bus error with Meteor and it turned out to be the "faker" package. It stopped after updating it to 5.1.0. ATM there's no fix so the alternative was to roll it back to 4.1.x. Here's the issue: https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/issues/1002

Answer (score 0):

It turns out an error in one of my SASS files (two files imported each other) broke everything without a proper error message. Weird stuff.